# Control doesn't move next to the select function

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

i am trying to implement a TCP server that accepts multiple client nodes. However, the control is just stuck at `select()` and not moving beyond that. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(2987);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &hint.sin_addr);

    bind(server_socket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(server_socket, SOMAXCONN);

    fd_set master;
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_SET(server_socket, &master);

    int client_socket;
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    while(true){
        fd_set copy = master;
        int socket_count = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        cout << "Reached here!" << endl;

        for(int i=0; i<socket_count; i++){
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &copy)){
                if(i == server_socket){
                    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_len);
                }else{
                    // Message
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the control never moves beyond the `select` statement. It just remain there even after i open a connection to the server with telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 2987
```

Why it stuck there and how do i get the client socket with this?

Comment: where does your `select()` function come from ? You may try to use a debugger to see where in the function the program is stuck

Comment: I've updated the code. Looking at the manual pages, i think it is coming from here: `sys/types.h` `unistd.h`

Comment: You should not be passing 0 to select, but the maximum FD you have: `select(server_socket, &copy, ...` . It's been over a decade since I last used `select`, so I'm not certain if this is the only issue

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Just checked, still same.

Comment: Also, give to `select()` some timeout might be safer, and will ensure the function return at some point.

Comment: I forgot + 1,  `select(server_socket + 1, ....`

Comment: No need for timeout. I have once written an instant messaging server that worked just fine without any timeout parameter

Comment: @MichaelVeksler `+1` did the trick. You can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the manual of select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

The first parameter should not be zero, but be the highest file-descriptor that select should manage plus 1. In your case it's:

```
int socket_count = select(server_socket + 1, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```